# How to unlock aspect ratio for new OLEObject added attachment?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to have Aspect Ratio unlocked for every new attachment added to an excel sheet. I'm not sure if it is easier to unlock the aspect ratio for ALL objects, or have it unlock for every new object added through the code.

I know how to change the aspect ratio of one set object, but I need to change it for either ALL objects in sheet or for every new one inserted.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("X" & ActiveCell.Row).Select

    Dim vFile As Variant, Sh As Object
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*", Title:="Find file to insert")
    If LCase(vFile) = "false" Then Exit Sub
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add Filename:=vFile, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
        "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{90110409-6000-11D3-8CFE-0150048383C9}\xlicons.exe", _
        IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=vFile

    Dim OleObj As OLEObject 'code works for one set object(1), I need for all

    Set OleObj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1)
    OleObj.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    OleObj.Height = 10
    OleObj.Width = 30
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the [Application.GetOpenFilename method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename) returns a boolean `False` not a string `"false"` so you need to check correctly `If vFile = False Then …`.

Also [OLEObjects.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobjects.add) returns the new added OLE Object:

> **Return value**
>   An OLEObject object that represents the new OLE object.

that return value can directly be set to your variable `OleObj`.

```
Set OleObj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(…)
```

So you can set your properties as wanted for every added OLE Object.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("X" & ActiveCell.Row).Select

    Dim vFile As Variant, Sh As Object
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*", Title:="Find file to insert")
    If vFile = False Then Exit Sub

    Dim OleObj As OLEObject
    Set OleObj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=vFile, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
        "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{90110409-6000-11D3-8CFE-0150048383C9}\xlicons.exe", _
        IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=vFile)
    OleObj.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    OleObj.Height = 10
    OleObj.Width = 30
End Sub
```

Comment: I see, thank you. But I was also wondering if there was a way to have this outputted attachment to be formatted as text or somehow to have it look like just a number rather than a stretched out icon/path. I tried changing the IconLabel:=Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row) to output the number of the row but it doesn't seem to output anything inside the object. Any ideas?